# undefined method `category_id' for #<Post:0xade8ce4>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model and a Category model. I installed simple_form gem with active record. I'm trying to implement [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) github steps of simple form association with foundation. But I'm getting this weird error which I can't resolve.

posts.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :body
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.association :category %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have a column category_id in your post model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the `category_id` in your post model as hd1 said.  You should make a migration:

`rails g migration AddIdToPost`

and in the migration file:

```
def change
  add_column :posts, :category_id, :integer
end
```

then run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: that did the trick. i'm new in rails and these silly things are yet to catch up. thanks for helping me out. :D